# ImportError upon execution of cx_freeze file

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I built a GUI tool using tkinter, and then used cx_Freeze to attempt convert the tool to a .exe for Windows users that do not have python installed. After double-clicking the cx_Freeze created .exe file, I got the following error. Any suggestions?

```
C:\Python35\build\exe.win-amd64-3.5>tcptest.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", lin
e 12, in <module>
    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 24
, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "tcptest.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Used the following to create the setup.py file (python 3.5):

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Python35\tcl\tk8.6'


setup(
    name = "FWMon Creator",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "xxx xxxx",
    description = "A tool to help create a FWMon command.",
    executables = [Executable("tcptest.py")])
```